# How to get a value of selected row in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have a Table View Controller in my swift application. How to I get a value of selected row (cell)? 
For example, I want to show a value of selected row with alert when the user clicked on row.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just implement the method:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var alert = UIAlertView()
    alert.delegate = self
    alert.title = "Selected Row"
    alert.message = "You selected row \(indexPath.row)"
    alert.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
    alert.show()
}
```

This delegate method gets fired whenever you select a row. Via `NSIndexPath` you get the exact `section` and `row` the user selected. In order to make sure the method gets called you need to make sure your tableview's `delegate` is set.

But since you are using an `UITableViewController` this should already be done automatically for you.

For further documentation see: [tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:)

Answer (score 3):

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        var selectedItem = indexPath  
        print (selectedItem.row) 
    }
```

You can handle this method
**SWIFT 3.0 Code**

Answer (score 2):

Use this function for it:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
 NSLog("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Swift 4:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    ...
}
```